# Options for Async Silverlight-to-WPF communication?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, cross-platform, communication, asynchronous

What's the fastest communication model for a Silverlight component communicating with a WPF component?   That is, at the very least I'd like to consume an event from a Silverlight component in a WPF component.

- I understand you can use WCF to build a bridge
- I understand you can use Javascript to bridge from WPF -> Silverlight (and I have that working)
- I understand you can use COM to go the other way (Silveright -> WPF)

However I'm looking for a tighter communication model (not using COM) - perhaps like EventAggregator (Silverlight component pubs, WPF component subs)...but I've only seen eventAggregation in WPF *or* Silverlight but not both at the same time.

Any ideas for creating such an eventAgg / eventBus, without using WCF, without using COM?

Open to any approaches / ideas; might be something I haven't considered.

Thanks.

Comment: Also - assume Windows-only deployment, since WPF is involved.

And by "tighter comm model" I don't mean tight-coupling.  EventAgg would be great but would need to be hosted on local PC, available to both Silverlight & WPF components. 

Am I crazy for even attempting this?   :)

Comment: ...Any ideas for creating such an eventAgg / eventBus, without using WCF, without using COM?         .             .           Exploring TCP/sockets, shared memory options too.

Comment: this may help some one
http://eneter.blogspot.com/2010/11/silverlight-how-to-receive-messages.html?showComment=1331198714279#c7370731825042576434

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge - could you provide a little more detail on why you need to do this?

My first question is: Are you envisioning these two apps running on the same machine, at the same time?  Both are important.

If the answer is yes (same machine, both running) then you should be able to implement a solution using WCF, with the service self-hosted in the WPF app, the Silverlight client referencing it, and a cross-domain policy setup appropriately.

If the answer is yes, but not at the same time, then you'll need a third party, like a Message Bus, perhaps implemented as a Windows Service.  [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) comes to mind.

In any case, WCF really is the best solution for messaging in Silverlight.  If you were going Silverlight app-to Silverlight app [there is a mechanism for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833063%28VS.95%29.aspx) that doesn't require WCF.

A message bus would give you the Event Aggregator functionality you're thinking of - a player who is always there to accept subscriptions and publications.

Another option (if running at the same time) is to elevate your Silverlight app to full-trust and use [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28VS.95%29.aspx).  See [this link](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/03/20/silverlight-4-rc-socket-security-changes.aspx) for more info (he provides an example that may be helpful).